# IdentityServer4 OpenIdConnect GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint not setting additional claims

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

Mvc Hybrid application is not getting extra claims other than name, given_name and family_name (which I set them in access token) in id_token from ProfileService.

Below is the claims issued at the end of **GetProfileDataAsync** of ProfileService

[image: Issued Claims from GetProfileDataAsync]

And here is what i get in id_token:

[image: Mvc Id_Token Claims]

missing the picture claim i set on ProfileService.

So the main confusion is here:

[image: Oidc Options]

**1. Isn't this mean to fetch UserInfo end point and merge them with
    id_token? If so, is this working as intended?**

**2.** If this is working as intended and **if I have to** set the claims in
    GetProfileDataAsynch

```
    if (context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderIdentityToken") //(Or AccessToken)
    {
       //Identity Token claims
    }
```

Why would I need to call UserInfo end point for profile scope? And if I have lots of scope requests wouldn't it exceed the maximum token size with lots of claims? **Futhermore** if I have to add all of them in id_token (or access token), what's the point of setting this property to **true**?

**3.** In case if i have many claims and when i wanted to get the UserInfo
    claims, do I need to call the UserInfo end point via acess token and merge
    them with identity token myself? Will it have exceeding the max
    token size problem? Or is it just a fool's errand?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Read this first: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/

Comment: Sooo, its kinda way of Microsoft's saying _"Ok, let me ignore them all except few incase you screw things up like token size. So you map manualy knowing what you are mapping"._

Comment: @leastprivilege can you promote this as an answer it was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue.. user claims are not mapped automatically.

To begin with my webapi bff(BackendForFrontEnd) configuration was something like below. And Identity server along with email claim emitted the claim "role".

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = _identityServerConfiguration.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = _identityServerConfiguration.ClientSecret;
            options.ResponseType = _identityServerConfiguration.ResponseType;
            options.UsePkce = _identityServerConfiguration.UsePkce;
            options.Authority = _identityServerConfiguration.AuthorityUrl;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            var scopesRequested = _identityServerConfiguration.Scope;
            var scopes = scopesRequested.Split(",");
            foreach (var scope in scopes)
            {
                options.Scope.Add(scope);
            }
```

But after Authentication when i tried to access

```
HttpContext.User.FindFirst("role");
HttpContext.User.FindFirst("email");
```

I got null for both values
Then I added the below setting in the AddOpenIdConnect method specified above.

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
```

After which

```
HttpContext.User.FindFirst("role"); --> It still gave null
HttpContext.User.FindFirst("email"); --> It worked.
```

Then I added below code in the AddOpenIdConnect method

```
 options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
```

After which

```
 HttpContext.User.FindFirst("role"); --> It Worked
 HttpContext.User.FindFirst("email"); --> It worked.
```

My final config was like:

```
 .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("grp", "Group");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = _identityServerConfiguration.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = _identityServerConfiguration.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = _identityServerConfiguration.ResponseType;
                options.UsePkce = _identityServerConfiguration.UsePkce;
                options.Authority = _identityServerConfiguration.AuthorityUrl;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                var scopesRequested = _identityServerConfiguration.Scope;
                var scopes = scopesRequested.Split(",");
                foreach (var scope in scopes)
                {
                    options.Scope.Add(scope);
                }
```

**Explaination:**
Initially id_token from cookie was used to build UserPrincipal

Then setting GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint to true made the UserPrincipal to use claims from access_token as well.

But it just worked for the name and email type of cliams.
Finally it was MapJsonKey which actually worked for the remainder of the claims

This article has an excellent explanation for this.
https://damienbod.com/2019/11/01/user-claims-in-asp-net-core-using-openid-connect-authentication/comment-page-1/?unapproved=139595&moderation-hash=e41d293e5b41b039a65a776a187c9af7#comment-139595